# Identifying and grouping similar items in a collection of strings

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a collection of strings like the following:

```
List<string> codes = new List<string>
{
    "44.01", "44.02", "44.03", "44.04", "44.05", "44.06", "44.07", "44.08", "46", "47.10"
};
```

Each string is made up of two components separated by a full stop - a prefix code and a subcode. Some of the strings don't have sub codes.

I want to be able combine the strings whose prefixes are the same and output them as follows with the other codes also:

> 44(01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08),46,47.10

I'm stuck at the first hurdle of this, which is how to identify and group together the codes whose prefix values are the same, so that I can combine them into a single string as you can see above.

Comment: You want a `linq` solution, or will a non-`linq` one suit?

Comment: Whatever does the job and is readable.

Comment: You could start by sorting your List! The default comparer will sort the List in [lexicograhical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). Then loop over the list and select the prefix. As long as it remains the same, you can append the suffix to your "sub list".

Comment: MrPaulch, I do advise caution when sorting numeric items if it is not guaranteed that the numbers are zero-padded to all have the same length.  For example, 11.0 will be considered to be before 5.0, even though 5.0 is smaller.  It works when you have 11.0 and 05.0, but we can't be sure his data is always zero-padded.

Comment: Why `47.10` is a special case? It also has a prefix & subcode right..?

Comment: @ManEatingCheese you are correct! In that case I would advise a custom comparer that *knows* that the string actually represents integers (**or** `LINQ` of course). But using a Dictionary<int, int> as proposed by some answers below, **is** a more robust solution, anyways.

Comment: @RahulSingh 47.10 is another possible combination, I've included it here along with 46 to demonstrate that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
var query = codes.Select(c => 
    new
    {
        SplitArray = c.Split('.'),  //to avoid multiple split
        Value = c
    })
    .Select(c => new
    {
        Prefix = c.SplitArray.First(), //you can avoid multiple split if you split first and use it later
        PostFix = c.SplitArray.Last(),
        Value = c.Value,
    })
    .GroupBy(r => r.Prefix)
    .Select(grp => new
    {
        Key = grp.Key,
        Items = grp.Count() > 1 ? String.Join(",", grp.Select(t => t.PostFix)) : "",
        Value = grp.First().Value,
    });
```

This is how it works:

- Split each item in the list on the delimiter and populate an anonymous type with `Prefix`, `Postfix` and original `value`
- Later group on `Prefix`
- after that select the values and the post fix values using `string.Join`

For output:

```
foreach (var item in query)
{
    if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Items))
        Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("{0}({1})", item.Key, item.Items);
}
```

Output would be:

```
44(01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08)
46
47.10
```

Comment: perfect answer, I verified the output in Fiddle. I actually had a separate query regarding eliminating any leading zeros in subcodes at [CodeReview StackExchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/96252/basic-string-manipulation-trim-leading-zeroes-from-second-component-of-a-strin) and wondered if you had a more elegant solution to the one I've provided?

Comment: @CiaranGallagher, thanks, Just replied to your query on CodeReview.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:-

```
 var result = codes.Select(x => new { SplitArr = x.Split('.'), OriginalValue = x })
                   .GroupBy(x => x.SplitArr[0])
                   .Select(x => new 
                    {
                       Prefix= x.Key,
                       subCode = x.Count() > 1 ? 
                             String.Join(",", x.Select(z => z.SplitArray[1])) : "",
                       OriginalValue = x.First().OriginalValue
                    });
```

You can print your desired output like this:-

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
     Console.Write("{0}({1}),",item.Prefix,item.subCode);
}
```

[**Working Fiddle.**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PKlHng)

Comment: A minor mistake, this one will return `47(10)` for the last value and not `47.10` as desired by the OP

Comment: @Habib - Thanks just saw, is that not a typo by OP? Why the last one is a special case..?

Comment: I guess , if the count is exactly one than the OP wants the original value, it could just be another use case.

Comment: @RahulSingh, the numbers aren't counts of anything, they are just codes linked to the business logic. In the case of 47, it has one subcode and it just happens to be 10.

Comment: @CiaranGallagher - Okay got it. Have updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Outlined idea:

- Use `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` for collecting your result
- in a loop over your list, use `string.split()` .. the first element will be your Dictionary key ... create a new `List<string>` there if the key doesn't exist yet
- if the result of split has a second element, append that to the List
- use a second loop to format that Dictionary to your output string

Of course, linq is possible too, e.g.

```
List<string> codes = new List<string>() {
    "44.01", "44.05", "47", "42.02", "44.03" };

var result = string.Join(",",
    codes.OrderBy(x => x)
    .Select(x => x.Split('.'))
    .GroupBy(x => x[0])
    .Select((x) =>
    {
        if (x.Count() == 0) return x.Key;
        else if (x.Count() == 1) return string.Join(".", x.First());
        else return x.Key + "(" + string.Join(",", x.Select(e => e[1]).ToArray()) + ")";
    }).ToArray());
```

Gotta love linq ... haha ... I think this is a monster.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all in one clever `LINQ`:

```
var grouped = codes.Select(x => x.Split('.'))
                   .Select(x => new
                   {
                       Prefix = int.Parse(x[0]),
                       Subcode = x.Length > 1 ? int.Parse(x[1]) : (int?)null
                   })
                   .GroupBy(k => k.Prefix)
                   .Select(g => new
                   {
                       Prefix = g.Key,
                       Subcodes = g.Where(s => s.Subcode.HasValue).Select(s => s.Subcode)
                   })
                   .Select(x =>
                       x.Prefix +
                       (x.Subcodes.Count() == 1 ? string.Format(".{0}", x.Subcodes.First()) :
                        x.Subcodes.Count() > 1 ? string.Format("({0})", string.Join(",", x.Subcodes))
                                                : string.Empty)
                   ).ToArray();
```

1. First it splits by `Code` and `Subcode`
2. Group by you `Code`, and get all `Subcode`s as a collection
3. Select it in the appropriate format

Looking at the problem, I think you should stop just before the last `Select` and let the data presentation be done in another part/method of your application.

Comment: A minor mistake, this one will return `47` for the last item, not `47.10` as asked by the OP

Comment: @Habib,  Corrected, more complex, that it appears

Answer (score 1):

The old fashioned way:

```
List<string> codes = new List<string>() {"44.01", "44.05", "47", "42.02", "44.03" };
string output="" 
for (int i=0;i<list.count;i++)
{
  string [] items= (codes[i]+"..").split('.') ;
  int pos1=output.IndexOf(","+items[0]+"(") ;
  if (pos1<0) output+=","+items[0]+"("+items[1]+")" ; // first occurence of code : add it
  else
  { // Code already inserted : find the insert point
    int pos2=output.Substring(pos1).IndexOf(')') ;   
    output=output.Substring(0,pos2)+","+items[1]+output.Substring(pos2) ;
  }
}
if (output.Length>0) output=output.Substring(1).replace("()","") ;
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work, including the correct formats for no subcodes, a single subcode, multiple subcodes.  It also doesn't assume the prefix or subcodes are numeric, so it leaves leading zeros as is.  Your question didn't show what to do in the case you have a prefix without subcode AND the same prefix with subcode, so it may not work in that edge case (44,44.01). I have it so that it ignores the prefix without subcode in that edge case.

```
List<string> codes = new List<string>
{
    "44.01", "44.02", "44.03", "44.04", "44.05", "44.06", "44.07", "44.08", "46", "47.10"
};
var result=codes.Select(x => (x+".").Split('.'))
                   .Select(x => new
                   {
                       Prefix = x[0],
                       Subcode = x[1]
                   })
                   .GroupBy(k => k.Prefix)
                   .Select(g => new
                   {
                       Prefix = g.Key,
                       Subcodes = g.Where(s => s.Subcode!="").Select(s => s.Subcode)
                   })
                   .Select(x =>
                       x.Prefix +
                       (x.Subcodes.Count() == 0 ? string.Empty :
                        string.Format(x.Subcodes.Count()>1?"({0})":".{0}",
                         string.Join(",", x.Subcodes)))
                   ).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

General idea, but i'm sure replacing the `Substring` calls with `Regex` would be a lot better as well

```
List<string> newCodes = new List<string>()
foreach (string sub1 in codes.Select(item => item.Substring(0,2)).Distinct)
{
    StringBuilder code = new StringBuilder();
    code.Append("sub1(");
    foreach (string sub2 in codes.Where(item => item.Substring(0,2) == sub1).Select(item => item.Substring(2))
        code.Append(sub2 + ",");
    code.Append(")");
    newCodes.Add(code.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go a couple ways... I could see you making a `Dictionary<string,List<string>>` so that you could have "44" map to a list of {".01", ".02", ".03", etc.}  This would require you processing the codes before adding them to this list (i.e. separating out the two parts of the code and handling the case where there is only one part).

Or you could put them into a a SortedSet and provide your own Comparator which knows that these are codes and how to sort them (at least that'd be more reliable than grouping them alphabetically).  Iterating over this SortedSet would still require special logic, though, so perhaps the Dictionary to List option above is still preferable.

In either case you would still need to handle a special case "46" where there is no second element in the code.  In the dictionary example, would you insert a String.Empty into the list?  Not sure what you'd output if you got a list {"46", "46.1"} -- would you display as "46(null,1)" or... "46(0,1)"... or "46(,1)" or "46(1)"?